# Should we avoid using words that have alternate offensive meaning

Tags: slang, formality, synonyms, minced-oaths

There are many English words that could be used to refer to something innocent that also has a common slang meaning, such as *pussy, ass, bitch*, etc.

For convenience' sake, should we avoid using those words altogether in formal writing? Should we perhaps use synonyms or paraphrase them, instead of using the single word?

Comment: I'm afraid that's **highly** subjective. I don't think you'll find a single, unifying, acceptable answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that somebody has come up with a slang, or even obscene, definition for just about any word you can think of.

Comment: @MT_Head: hehe, "word", right.

Comment: This reminds me of this old CBC comedy classic: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W6iSk9vsK_E

Comment: [Word.](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=word)

Comment: Or all of the stories about Samantha and her elderly gentlemen friends in I'm Sorry I haven't a Clue.

Comment: Your choice of words is part of how you represent yourself to the world. If you consistently use certain words, people won't be offended, but they will form opinions about you. So if you want to present an inoffensive persona then, sure, go ahead and use inoffensive synonyms.

But never substitute words mindlessly. For instance, I have a few anecdotes of white Americans who internalised *African-American* as a safe synonym for *black* (or maybe even *nigger*), and went on to apply the term to all blacks, regardless of nationality. They'd have caused far less offence just saying "black".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would say, as in so many instances: **it depends**.  The three words you singled out, *pussy*, *ass*, and *bitch*, have all been "taken over" by their more obscene meanings - that is, an average listener<sup>1</sup> will either be confused, or at least temporarily distracted, if you use these words.  For "pussy", I would substitute *kitty*; for "ass", I would use *donkey*; for "bitch"... unfortunately *female dog* is the shortest substitute I can think of.

Of course, these words still retain their original meanings, and it's silly to avoid them if you are writing for a purpose or for an audience where the original meaning is not only clear but central to the work.  If you're a professional dog breeder, **of course** you use the word "bitch"; otherwise it becomes very hard to talk about breeding dogs.  If you're writing a paper about *Equus africanus*, by all means call it the Wild African Ass; "donkey" would be not only inconvenient but wrong.  If you are writing about the *Salix discolor* tree, call it a pussy willow!  But in almost any other context, these words (and I'm sure we can all think of a few other, similar examples) will prove more of a distraction than a help.

That being said, people come up with obscene meanings for innocent words all the time, and if you try to avoid all words that could possibly be misinterpreted, you'll never get any writing done!  **Bone**, for instance, is commonly used as a euphemism for "fuck" - but only a teenager will giggle if you talk about "the bones of the inner ear".  **Come** is, of course, commonly used to mean *ejaculate* (both verb and noun)<sup>2</sup>, but it would be silly to avoid using such a common verb simply because some sixth-grader might be titillated.

<sup>1</sup> At least in the United States; I can't speak for anyone else.
<sup>2</sup> Come to think of it, **ejaculate** is another word you should probably avoid, even though it has a perfectly innocuous meaning as well as a sexual one.

Comment: I think that the words where the obscene meanings have overtaken the other one are *still* used in their respective fields. I've heard breeders talk about a bitch without any signs of discomfort.

Comment: @Joachim - In their respective fields, yes... but if you're *not* a dog breeder, you should probably find some other word for "bitch".   The OP asked about "formal writing".  If you are writing a paper about *Equus africanus*, by all means call it the African Wild Ass!  But if you're writing for any other purpose or audience, those three words (and a few others) will be, at best, a distraction.  Which part of **it depends** and **average listener** was unclear?

Comment: nothing was unclear, I didn't mean to imply that. I just thought it could be mentioned explicitly.

Comment: Totally agree on the Distraction part. For me, I would stick to words that doesn't at least distract me. Also for general writings such as Blogs, avoid them as much as possible. Same for written exams I guess.

Answer (score 6):

It's not the words so much as their context.

For example

> Keep a firm grasp on your pole as you peak

is perfectly innocent as pole-vaulting advice, but suggestive in other contexts.

Same for pussy, bitch, and ass.